# What are the techniques that VLC media player follows to assure software Quality?

Tags: bug-report, quality-assessment, open-source, quality-assurance

I wanna know about the vlc media player's software quality techniques, how they assure the quality of product (detailed).
I would like to know the following facts:

- What development model they follow ?
- By which method testing is done? Is there any further software developed for testing ?
- How bug reporting works (detailed process)?
- How they cooperates within teams to maintain software quality?
- What are the challanges they face day to day?

---

```
                                     THANKS
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is specifically related to the development and testing processes followed by the VLC team internally and it would be best if the Nischay contacts their support team to get the answers!

Answer (score 1):

This question is highly dependent on that specific product and its unlikely any of  us know how the VLC team tests their product in detail. You'd be better off asking such questions on their forum (https://forum.videolan.org/), their IRC channel or by visiting their bug tracker (https://trac.videolan.org/vlc).